# Crystal reports magenta image background instead of transparent

Tags: image, background, crystal-reports, transparent

I am using an OLE Object to display images in a Crystal report's listing. Its purpose is to not to have to store the image data in the dataset, but in a computer local path.

The images are .PNG files with transparent background. I see all the images with a magenta background!
[image]

Is there a way to render the background transparent?

Thanks

Comment: There is no BG Transparency, better u can use JPEG Image with white color as background

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately crystal reports doesn't support image transparency for images.
I don't know of any work around and have looked many times, hopefully someone will work one out.